# How do I remove the second x and y axes in R?

Tags: r, plot, pca, vegan

Hopefully a simple question today:

I'm plotting an RDA (in R Studio) and would like to remove the second X and Y (top and right) axes . Purely for aesthetic purposes, but still. The code I'm using is below. I've managed to remove the first axes (I'll replace them with something nicer later) with xaxt="n" and yaxt="n", but it still puts the others in.

*The question: How do I remove the top and right axes from a plot in R?*

To make this example reproducible you will need two data frames of equal length called "bio" and "abio" respectively.

```
library (vegan) ##not sure which package I'm actually employing
library(MASS)   ##these are just my defaults
rdaY1<-rda(bio,Abio) #any dummy data will do so long as they're of equal length
par(bg="transparent",new=FALSE)
plot(rdaY1,type="n",bty="n",main="Y1. P<0.001 R2=XXX",
     ylab="XXX% variance explained",
     xlab="XXX% variance explained",
     col.main="black",col.lab="black", col.axis="white",
     xaxt="n",yaxt="n",axes=FALSE, bty="n")
abline(h=0,v=0,col="black",lwd=1)
points(rdaY1,display="species",col="gray",pch=20)
#text(rdaY1,display="species",col="gray")
points(rdaY1,display="cn",col="black",lwd=2)
text(rdaY1,display="cn",col="black")
```

UPDATE: Using comments below I've played around with various ways to get rid of the axes and it seems like that second "points" command where I call for the vectors to be plotted is the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for `bty = "n"`? Or perhaps `axes = FALSE`?

Comment: It's considered polite to supply the test data `bio` and `Abio`. Any dummy data to make the program self-contained are ok. And I guess a library() call is also missing

Comment: @Daniel Anderson: Looks like those worked in the plot command, but "points" calls them back. I added those commands to both "points" sections as well, but I still got the axis lines back.

Comment: @Dieter Menne: I've tried a few ways of supplying dummy data in the past, and keep getting dinged for it. I'm not a strong programmer by any means (it's just a tool that I've been trying to teach myself), so I'm unfamiliar with how to generate dummy data via code. could you recommend a string that would be appropriate?

Comment: @Daniel Anderson: Update: it looks like the problem is only in the second points command, where I call for the vectors.

Comment: As @DieterMenne suggests, it would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example. Perhaps with one of the datasets from the vegan package. I tried with `mod <- rda(dune ~ 1, dune.env)`, which is in the package documentation, but I wasn't able to fully replicate it. If I removed `display = "cn"` on your points call it seemed to work, but I'm not sure if that will give you your expected output.

Comment: Re supplying data: in most cases, it is easiest to use date from the package you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`bty="L"` worked for me. I generated some random data using `rnorm()` to test:

```
library(vegan)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10)
pl <- rda(mat)
plot(pl, bty="L")
```

Here's the result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried a few configurations of this answer and it didn't seem to fix the problem on my end. Is there any way you could explain how best to integrate it in to the above code? I think the Y2 and top axes are being drawn by the vector plotting line, but putting the bty="L" there didn't seem to effect it.

Comment: Does copying and pasting my example work at least? Have you tried starting with minimal code (i.e. just the data and `btw="L"`) and building it up from that?

Comment: Yes, I still get the axes I'm trying to get rid of but also get the Y1 and X1 (like in your example plot) because the vectors are plotted on the y2 and x2.
 Using the code:
**
plot(rdaY1,bty="L",main="Y1. P<0.001 R2=XXX",
     ylab="XXX% variance explained",
     xlab="XXX% variance explained",
     col.main="black",col.lab="black", bty="n",col.axis="white",
     axes=FALSE)
**
I get rid of x1 and y1, but still ahve the others

Comment: OK. I think the only way is to somehow show us the desired output either as a link or graphic, otherwise it's hard to help further.